# jquery defer and promises with getScript

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I've been investigating the new(ish) deferred object in jQuery and I stumbled across this website article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/scriptjunkie/gg723713.aspx) .

In the article is some code designed to cache scripts so they don't get requested more than once.

```
    var cachedScriptPromises = {};

    $.cachedGetScript = function( url, callback ) {
        if ( !cachedScriptPromises[ url ] ) {
            cachedScriptPromises[ url ] = $.Deferred(function( defer ) {
                $.getScript( url ).then( defer.resolve, defer.reject );
            }).promise();
        }
        return cachedScriptPromises[ url ].done( callback );
    };

// You would then call it like thus.
$.cachedGetScript( url ).then( successCallback, errorCallback );
```

What this looked like to me was a way to ensure that your script will only get executed if your `$.getScript()` was successful.

As far as my experiments have gone though the error callback never gets called even if I supply an incorrect url.

Have I missed something obvious or is the code sample wrong?

Note: I'd have asked this question on the site but the commenting system didn't work. :-S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly sure that that script cannot work on cross-domain requests.

`$.getScript` works in different ways for local and cross-domain requests.  For local requests, it loads the content via AJAX then runs it.  Since this is a normal AJAX operation, errors occur in the normal way.  That code works fine, as far as I can test it.

For cross-domain requests, however, it works by inserting `script` tags into the document.  `error` handlers are never fired for the `script` elements that are inserted, so your `error` callbacks will never fire.

Comment: That's a damn shame. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: That could well depend on whether `.getScript` has support for both [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-Origin_Resource_Sharing) and injecting script tags. Even the latter might be capable of supporting deferred's but whether it currently does or not I do not know.

Comment: @lonesomeday, are you sure that for local request it will runs via ajax? if so why when calling $.ajax for a local script, it only returns the data but doesn't execute it?

Comment: @adardesign My answer is loosely worded: by "local" I mean "on the same domain as the original request".

Answer (score 0):

But...you may delegate the remote url check to a (e.g.) php file.

```
            checkremotefile: function( remotefile, options ) {
                options = $.extend( options || {}, {
                    dataType:   'html',
                    cache:      false,
                    url:        'ajax/checkfile.php?url=' + escape(remotefile),
                    error:      function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
                                    $(this).coresystem('errorlog',jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown);
                    },
                    success:    function (data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
                                    if (data!='200') {

                                    // ....call errorhandler

                                    }
                    }
                });
                return jQuery.ajax( options );
            },
```

checkfile.php:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_REQUEST['url'])) die( 'param url missing!');
if (!preg_match('/.*\.js$/',$_REQUEST['url'])) die( 'filetype not allowed');
$ch = curl_init($_REQUEST['url']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_exec($ch);
$code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
// $code 404 not found, $code = 200 found.
curl_close($ch);
echo($code);
```

Not 100% reliable, but better then nothing...